# Подключения style.css

Tags: style

Я сделал сайт на zerver.ru , не плохое обслуживания но лимит обращения уже запарил, и я переехал на hut.ru , но там у меня не хочет подключаться style.css

Посмотрите пожалуйста , и подскажите что сделать:

[Сайт от zerver.ru](http://refresh.zg5.ru)

[Сайт от hut.ru](http://refresh.hut2.ru/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в отладчике файл стилей style.css загружаеться. Из чего делаем вывод - проблема не в этом.

PS: мде.... дела

```
  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql-4.zerver.ru' (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
```

вот ответ на твой вопрос

```
/перед style.css
```

Comment: пробовал, ноль на массу

Comment: проверяй пути,значит где то косяк,проверь htaccess

Comment: Да подключается стиль, о чем вы?